# I want to SAVE DATA into my sql using codeigniter, but when I click the submit button,it shows error page cannot be found

Tags: codeigniter

I want to SAVE DATA into my sql using codeigniter, but when I click the 
    submit button,it shows error page cannot be found  ....the view file shows but on click on submit button it shows error on next page.........
   my view file

add.php

```
<html>
     <head>
      <title>Insert Employee Records in Database</title>
      </head>
     <body>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url('emp_add/save'); ?>" method="post">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>First Name:</td>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'fname', 'name'=>'fname', 
      'placeholder' => 'First Name', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name:</td>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'lname', 'name'=>'lname', 
     'placeholder' => '
        <tr>lname', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'email', 'name'=>'email', 
       'placeholder' => 'Email', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Credits:</td>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'credits', 
      'name'=>'credits', 
          'placeholder' => 'credits', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" >ADD</button>
         </td>
        </tr>     
      </table>
      </form>
      </body>
     </html>
```

my controller file

emp_addd.php

```
 <?php class Emp_add extends CI_Controller  {   
     public function_construct()    {       
      parent:: _construct();        
    $this->load->model('employee_model'); 
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));  
    } 

   public function index()      
  {     
    $this->load->view('add');   }
        public function save()      {
        $this->load->model('employee_model');        
          if($this->input->post('submit'))
                {

                $this->employee_model->process();                
                }
            redirect('emp_add');
     }
```

my model file

employee_model.php

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access
    allowed');    class Employee_model extends CI_Model   {
         public function process()
         {
             $save = array(
            'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
            'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'credits' => $this->input->post('credits')  
        );
                    $this->db->insert('customers',$save);    
            }     
        } }

   ?>
```

SHOWING VIEW PAGE WELL. BUT ON SUBMIT IT SHOWS ERROR

Comment: Couple checks make sure your controller filename like`Emp_add.php` and then `class Emp_add extends CI_Controller {}` where the first letter only is upper case. If that does not work you may need a htaccess in main directory.

Comment: ya it works after add .htaccess file ....thank u